# Is it a good idea to send integers instead of strings over SSL to save bandwidth?

Tags: encryption, ssl, websocket

I am creating an app with client-server design. The client and server communicate with each other by sending data as binary message (CBOR array) via WebSocket. Instead of sending strings, I have created a dictionary mapped with integers like this:

```
const DICT: &[&str] = &[
    "USERNAME_NOT_AVAILABLE",
    "USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_DID_NOT_MATCHED",
    ....blablba long list ....
];

// genrates code like this:-
// pub const USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_DID_NOT_MATCHED : u16 = 4;
fn gen_rust(version: &String) -> String {
    let mut code = format!(
        "//generated code from Examer server version {}\n\n",
        version
    );
    for (index, element) in DICT.iter().enumerate() {
        code.push_str(&format!("pub const {} : u16 = {};\n", element, index))
    }
    code
}
```

The generated dictionary is then shared between client and server and I send integers instead of strings.

This approach does provide benefits like autocompletion and compile time errors if I do spelling mistakes which I do a lot but does this reduce the size of messages when encrypted with SSL? I heard that if the message is too small then padding is added and thus my main goal of reducing the size of the message wont be achieved.

Comment: It is not clear at all what message you even send with TLS. Assuming that you send 100 values in one message, where each value was 100 byte before getting mapped to an integer and only 2 byte if represented as integer then obviously the message gets way smaller. If you map only a single 3 byte string to a 2 byte integer then any difference is mostly irrelevant instead since the overhead of all the other  protocol layers is dominant.

Answer (score 1):

The modern TLS cipher suites (which are the only ones available in TLS 1.3 and the only ones allowed for HTTP/2) do not use padding. This is because AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 are based on CTR, not CBC.

Note that the padding in (obsolete) CBC cipher suites is up to 16 bytes per message, usually considered insignificant.

Note that the framing for websocket and the framing of a TLS record and the MAC are all bandwidth overhead which you can't remove. You can't just send the raw CBOR value, encrypted with some length preserving encryption.

You should use wireshark to observe how much data is actually sent when your application sends a message.